# C# Reading from a specific colum in sql

Tags: c#, mysql

I recently started to code and started a project. 
A lot of the questions I had were answered really well in here,
but now I can't find an answer to the problem I have now.
I want to read a column in a MariaDB-SQL-Server which is running on my pc via XAMPP.

```
            string[] bets = e.ChatMessage.Message.Split(' ');
            string bet = bets[1];
            string readbetuser = "SELECT * FROM bet_user";
            string readbetusername = "SELECT username * FROM bet_user WHERE username =@betusername ";
            string writebetp = "INSERT INTO betp(`id`, `username`, `Munie`) VALUES (NULL, '" +e.ChatMessage.Username + "', '" + Convert.ToInt32(bet) + "')";
            string updateMunieMain = "'UPDATE bet_user SET Munie=@munieupdate, WHERE username='" + e.ChatMessage.Username;
            MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlConnection databaseConnection1 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlConnection databaseConnection2 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlConnection databaseConnection3 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlCommand readusername = new MySqlCommand(readbetuser, databaseConnection);
            MySqlCommand readbetname = new MySqlCommand(readbetusername, databaseConnection1);
            MySqlCommand commandDatabase2 = new MySqlCommand(writebetp, databaseConnection2);
            MySqlDataAdapter commandDatabase3 = new MySqlDataAdapter(updateMunieMain, databaseConnection3);
            readusername.CommandTimeout = 60;
            commandDatabase2.CommandTimeout = 60;
            //commandDatabase3.CommandTimeout = 60;
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            MySqlDataReader reader1;
            //MySqlDataReader reader2;
            //MySqlDataAdapter reader3;

            try
            {
                databaseConnection.Open();
                databaseConnection1.Open();
                databaseConnection2.Open();
                databaseConnection3.Open();
                reader = readusername.ExecuteReader();
                reader1 = readbetname.ExecuteReader();
                //reader2 = commandDatabase2.ExecuteReader();
                //reader3 = commandDatabase3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int testvar = 0;

                if(reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read() & testvar < 1)
                    {
                        readbetname.Parameters.AddWithValue("@betusername", e.ChatMessage.Username);
                        int betvalid = 1 ; //reads if the user has money from the database
                         //entryvalid = reader1 ; //reads if the user already has entered the betsystem

                        if (betvalid > 0 & Convert.ToInt32(bet) <= betvalid & Convert.ToInt32(bet) > 0 & e.ChatMessage.Username == e.ChatMessage.Username) //the bet worked
                        {
                            int munieupdate = betvalid - Convert.ToInt32(bet);
                            //commandDatabase3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", e.ChatMessage.Username);
                            //commandDatabase3.("@munieupdate", munieupdate);
                            commandDatabase3.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=e.ChatMessage.Username;
                            commandDatabase3.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@munieupdate", SqlDbType.Int).Value = munieupdate;
                            client.SendMessage($"Your bet has been placed successfuly @{e.ChatMessage.Username}");
                            testvar++;
                        }
```

This is from a "Twitch-Bot" I'm currently working on and I want to implement a bet system. Now I the thing that doesnt work is "readbetusername". 
It seems like it doesn't want to look for the username in the column I have in the table. 
How do I tell the program to look into the column and look for the username who send the message? ( the same problem will obviously occur when I try to read the column "Munie" to read if the user has enough Munie to bet the amount)
Speaking of that, is there a possibility to do that too? Read the column "Munie" which is linked to the username who placed the bet in the first place?

Comment: The commandtext used for _readbetusername_ requires a parameter. You don't add a parameter before calling ExecuteReader. This will trigger an exception

Comment: @Steve Didnt I do that on top? Where it says "string readbetusername = "SELECT username * FROM bet_user WHERE username =@betusername "; ?

Comment: `SELECT username *` is not going to work. `*` means all columns. You either use * or column names (yes, there are exceptions, but in this case, remove the `*` if you want your query to work.

Comment: @oerkelens Ok, I did it, but now there is still an exception which says "Unknown column 'hurri08' in 'where clause'... Shouldnt it now look in the column "username" for the name "hurri08" instead seeing that as a column?

Comment: And where do you set the parameter _@betusername_ BEFORE calling the ExecuteReader for the command that uses the _readbetusername_ string?

Comment: Oh god... that was it... That was it... after setting up a variable for that and put it in " ' " it worked... Thank you @Steve !